# Calling functions on require()d modules in Lua gives me "attempt to index local 'x' (a boolean value)"

Tags: module, lua

I've read PIL and the [ModulesTutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial) on creating modules but I'm having trouble `require()`ing them correctly.

Here is my setup:

```
-- File ./lib/3rdparty/set.lua
local ipairs = ipairs
module( "set" )
function newSet (t)
  local set = {}
  for _, l in ipairs(t) do set[l] = true end
  return set
end
```

And:

```
-- File ./snowplow.lua
local set = require( "lib.3rdparty.set" )
module( "snowplow" )
local SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS = set.newSet { "pc", "tv", "mob", "con", "iot" }
```

Then if I run `snowplow.lua`:

```
lua: snowplow.lua:4: attempt to index local 'set' (a boolean value)
stack traceback:
  snowplow.lua:4: in main chunk
  [C]: ?
```

What am I doing wrong in my module definition - what is the boolean exactly? Also, if I append a `return _M;` at the bottom of my `set.lua`, then everything starts working - why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`true` is usually returned by `require` if `module` function is not used inside module and module code doesn't return a value.
But anyway it seems strange.

```
-- file m0.lua
module'm0'


--file dir1\m1.lua
module'm1'


--file test.lua
print(require'm0')
print(m0)

print(require'dir1.m1')
print(m1)

for k,v in pairs(package.loaded) do
   if k:match'm%d' then print(k, v) end
end


--output
table: 0036C8C8
table: 0036C8C8
true
table: 0036B6B0
m0      table: 0036C8C8
m1      table: 0036B6B0
dir1.m1 true
```

So, you can simply use global variable `set` instead of local `set` assigned a value returned by `require`.

---

**UPD :**
It is recommended to avoid using `module` function and always `return` your table at the end of your module.  In that case the whole picture is just fine:

```
-- file m0.lua
return 'string0'


--file dir1\m1.lua
return 'string1'


--file test.lua
print(require'm0')
print(m0)

print(require'dir1.m1')
print(m1)

for k,v in pairs(package.loaded) do
   if k:match'm%d' then print(k, v) end
end


--output
string0
nil
string1
nil
m0      string0
dir1.m1 string1
```

---

**UPD2 :**
Problem disappears if you replace `module( "set" )` with `module('lib.3rdparty.set')`.
So, **each module must remember its relative path**.
Now you could access it either by calling `require'lib.3rdparty.set'` or by reading global variable `lib.3rdparty.set` - the result would be the same.

Comment: Wow - that's a really good discovery in your **UPD2** Egor, thanks for sharing. Marking as the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
require("lib.moduleName")
local moduleName = moduleName
```

I'm not sure why Lua returns a boolean when you require a module on a different directory, but it seems the module is correctly set on the the global variable. So I simply used that and put it on a local variable with the same name.